# Emergency Mode and Local Disk

Tags: centos, systemd, fstab

I have added this entry to my /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /user_data xfs rw 0 0
```

Which works fine, the issue i am getting it sometime i remove this drive and when i do and  reboot my machine it goes into emergency mode.

I have tried adding

```
/etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.d/nofail.conf
```

with 
`OnFailure=`  in it but i  still get the same result

is there something else i can do to stop this happening

Thanks

Comment: If the file _only_ has `OnFailure=` in it, I think you are missing the `[Unit]` heading.  If you just run `systemctl daemon-reload` after the system booted succesfully and check `journalctl -b`... or alternatively, boot with `printk.devkmsg=on` and check `journalctl -b` or `dmesg`... do you see systemd reporting any warnings parsing your drop-in config file?  You can also look at `systemctl show local-fs.target | grep OnFailure`

Comment: Sorry, i had added the [Unit] heading but it still failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `nofail` option to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1 /user_data xfs rw,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: My understanding was that on its own, this waits 90 seconds for the device to appear before continuing with the boot process, and this is usually longer than desired.  _editted to add:_ To be fair, the same would apply if you allowed local-fs.target to fail, without switching the system to emergency mode.

Comment: @sourcejedi: Absence of the `nofail` option when the device is not present at boot time yields outcomes that vary from system to system. For example, on `Raspbian`, the boot process may halt indefinitely, and in fact it does halt indefinitely in some cases. Smells like a bug, but in any case, the documentation (`man fstab`, `man mount`) is misleading in at least some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The options `noauto,x-systemd.automount` (in place of `rw`, which is enabled by default) can be used to attempt to mount the disk only when `/user_data` is accessed.  I do not know whether `fsck` is invoked first, however.